# Google_Client returns empty object in Laravel

Tags: php, youtube-api, laravel-5.4, youtube-data-api

I am trying to access YouTube live stream API and for that I have taken sample code from [google v3 API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/code_samples/php) with title *Create a broadcast and stream* but `$client` is always set to null(because of authorization failure).

```
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'REPLACE_ME';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'REPLACE_ME';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);
```

Note : I have updated it with my `clientId` and `client_secret`

I am using Laravel 5.4 and have used these statements to import Google_Client:

```
use Google_Client;
use Google_Service_YouTube;
```

I tried require_once but it throws error[main(): Failed opening required], and didn't worked.
As $client returns null rest of the code is not working for me. I tried rest of the solutions available on SO also didn't worked.

I have downloaded GitHub repo of samples and executing php script in that directory only, even then I am getting this error of `Authorization Failed`.

Please point out what I missed.

Comment: What's the full error string? Did you `composer update` after adding Google Client package to `composer.json`?

Comment: Yes I ran composer update, and there is a check in the code if($client->getAccessToken()){...} now as $client is null it goes to else block and gives no error.

Comment: However when I use require_once 'vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/autoload.php';, it gives error that : main(): Failed opening required 'vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

Comment: Did you set redirect url in google console?

Comment: Yes, I set it to http://localhost:8000, can it be a problem to set it on local?